# The C Programming Language, 1st Edition, Exercise 1-8 --- Can't get arrow to appear

Tags: c, mingw

I am going through Kernighan and Ritchie's *The C Programming Language* and am having problems with one of the exercises. I'm using, I believe, the first edition and Exercise 1-8 states:

*Write a program to replace each tab by the three-character sequence >, backspace, -, which prints as (right facing arrow), and each backspace by the similar sequence (left facing arrow). This makes the tabs and backspaces visible.* My code is displayed below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int c;

main(){
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c == '\t'){
            putchar('>');
            putchar('\b');
            putchar('-');
        }
        else if(c == '\b'){
            putchar('<');
            putchar('\b');
            putchar('-');
        }
        else
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
```

I am using the MinGW compiler and when I run the code I get a bunch of dashes with nothing in the way of arrows. I also don't see the < or > at all. I tried looking up other people's solutions to this exercise but all I found have been second edition versions of this book and the corresponding exercise has you counting the tabs. Finally, I tried running code with just the three putchar()s to get an arrow to no effect; I only get the same dash again.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Hope to hear from you,

Yusif Nurizade

Comment: Try to put `fflush(stdout) ;` at the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: Is it possible the backspace is deleting the < as soon as you print it?

Comment: Maybe the text means printing to a real printer with real paper and real ink; it doesn't work like described on a modern terminal.

Comment: The first edition, published in 1978, is a great book, but it uses an obsolete pre-standard version of the language. Get a copy of the second edition if you can. (It's available on Kindle and Nook if that's helpful.)

Comment: dude, this is for a teletype, not a computer monitor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that the program was written for obsolete systems.

If you run that program on a typical system with typical input settings, the program will never see a backspace character.

On Unix-like systems, for example, standard input (`stdin`) is typically processed a line at a time; a program reading a character at a time reads from an internal buffer. When you type a backspace, it doesn't send a backspace character to your program; it actually removes the previous character from its internal buffer.

For example, if you type "abcx<kbd>Backspace</kbd>def", the program will only see "abcdef".

If you're on a Unix-like system, you can enter a literal backspace by preceding it with <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>. And the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key on your keyboard might be mapped to <kbd>Delete</kbd>; if so, try <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd> to send a literal backspace character.

(If you're not on a Unix-like system, there may be a way to do something similar, but I don't know what it is.)

But even so, as [Michael Walz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22866861/827263) points out, the kind of overstriking that program uses (printing > backspace - to print a right arrow) would almost certainly work only on a hard-copy terminal. On a modern display terminal, the backspace will simply erase the previous character.

And to repeat what I wrote in a comment: the first edition of Kernighan & Ritchie (K&R1), published in 1978, is truly a classic, but it describe an obsolete pre-standard version of the C language. The biggest change since its publication is probably the addition of *prototypes*, function declarations that specify the types of the arguments; they didn't exist in 1978, but failing to use prototypes in modern C code is very poor practice. If you can get a copy of the second edition, do so. It's available on Kindle and Nook as well as on dead trees. (Even the second edition, published in 1989, is somewhat dated, but you can still learn C from it; good C89/C90 code is generally still good C99 and C11 code.)

Comment: I had a suspicion that the edition was causing the problem since an internet search always came back with second edition answers. I found the second edition online in .pdf format instead. Fortunately I'm at the beginning of the book so most of it has been basic enough to remain the same across editions.

Thanks again.

Comment: @Yusif_Nurizade: If you have the book in PDF format, it's almost certainly an unauthorized (i.e., pirated) copy.

Comment: That's a good point. I guess I thought since it was so old that it might have gone into the public domain. It's for the best anyway, I could never acclimate myself to reading a book on PDF. Will look for it in the iStore.

Answer (score 2):

That's normal.

```
putchar('>');   // prints the '>'
putchar('\b');  // prints a backspace which erases the previously printed '>'
```

**EDIT:**

Actually on my system with following program :

```
void main()
{
   while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
     printf ("%d\n",  c) ;
}
```

and this input ([Bs] = backspace keypressed, [Enter] = Enter key pressed)

```
 ABCDEF[Bs][Bs][Bs][Enter]
```

I get this output:

```
65
66
67
10
```

instead of:

```
65
66
67
68
69
70
8
8
8
10
```

because on my system the backspace will not be returned by `getchar()`. `8` being the ASCII code of BS (Backspace).

Comment: The behaviour of backspace depends on the console and platform you are using. It's not always destructive,  but in this case it appears to be.

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, or `int main()` if you're using the pre-standard language described in K&R1. `void main()` is non-standard, and there is no good reason to use it.

Comment: @KeithThompson: well it doesn't really matter here, but you are prefectly right.

Comment: How does it not really matter? A compiler can simply reject a program that uses `void main()`, and even if it doesn't, its behavior is undefined unless the compiler happens to document that it's supported. (I still fail to understand how the `void main()` fad even got started. The same standard that introduced the `void` keyword explicitly stated that `main` returns `int`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson IMHO, there's famous book in china written by tan Hao qiang which teach `void main()` and `main()`. And someone may learn `public static void main()` before c. And I do some quick search and found most of them running Turbo C IDE. e.g. http://www.circuitstoday.com/how-to-use-turbo-c

Comment: @林果皞: Regardless of its fame, that book is giving poor advice. `main()` is ok in some old versions of C, but at least `int main()` is better, and `int main(void)` is better yet. As for `public static void main()`, that's not even C, so it shouldn't be relevant. A compiler is permitted, but not required, to accept `void main()`. All conforming hosted C compilers are required to accept `int main(void)`. Unless you're using a freestanding implementation there is quite simply no good reason to use `void main()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson Actually my comment just try to explain how the void main() fad even got started. Java background will give wrong assumption that's no warning when they try to put void without enable -Wall or use turbo c IDE ( https://www.quora.com/Why-do-most-colleges-in-India-teach-you-to-use-void-main ). not only  tan Hao qiang, because even some ancient book like borland turbo c 1988 reference (e.g. https://ia801600.us.archive.org/4/items/bitsavers_borlandturReferenceGuide1988_19310204/Turbo_C_Version_2.0_Reference_Guide_1988.pdf) have this flaw.